# Convert a Pandas series with strings to a list for creating encoded variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas series with lists stored as strings. I'd like to convert strings to list and also deal with any bad data. Here's some data:

```
df['vals']

"['A']"
"['B', 'C, ', 'D', 'E']"
"['G', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'A, T']"

type(df['vals'][1]) 
str

Expected output:

df['vals']

['A']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['G', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'A, T']

type(df['vals'][1]) 
list
```

In case of any errors due to bad data, drop the element from the list or skip the string entirely. My objective is to have the data stored as `lists`, so that I can use `.explode()` to extract elements from the list and create new encoded variables.

Comment: how would bad data look like?

Comment: Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: @enke In `"['B', 'C, ', 'D', 'E']"`, 2 element has additional `,`. That's one example we can try to deal with.

Comment: @MattDMo I get `ValueError: malformed node or string: 0` when running `ast.literal_eval(df['vals'])`. I suppose need a way to handle `errors` due to bad data.

Comment: Right. You'll have to use something like `df.apply` to apply `ast.literal_eval` to each member of `df["vals"]`.

Comment: Do you always have single letters?

Comment: @mozway - nope, most of them are not single letters. I simplified the example for SO post.

Comment: Can you give a exhaustive list of potential characters? I provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787242/16343464) but it can certainly be improved depending on the real data.

Comment: So in the end you don't care about the misplaced quotes? I don't understand how the selected answer addresses your question. `ast.literal_eval` requires correct syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misplaced commas in your sample input, but assuming they are correct in the read data, use this:

```py
import ast
df["vals"] = df["vals"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: I think this is what OP called **bad data**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have complex input, one option would be to use a regex.

Just keep the word characters for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': ["['A']",
                            "['B', 'C, ', 'D', 'E']",
                            "['G', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'A, T']"]})
df['vals'].str.findall(r'\w+')

# or
# df['vals'].str.findall(r"[^\[\],' ]+")
```

output:

```
0                   [A]
1          [B, C, D, E]
2    [G, H, L, P, A, T]
Name: vals, dtype: object
```

output (last row only): `['G', 'H', 'L', 'P', 'A', 'T']`